# Ошибка TS1003: Identifier expected. при выборке из монго.Как мне вытащить данные из переменной?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, выборка

Возникает ошибка TS1003 хотя данные записанные при выборке из монго выглядят так
{_id: 1
'Шаг 1':'какая то информация',
'Шаг 2':'дата любая'
}
как мне вытянуть в массив данные о шаги 1

```
const mOLK= await find( {"Шаг 2": "2016-01-29T00:00:00+03:00" } ,'Record', 'tRecord');
    let OperationId=[];
    for(const OpId of  mOLK)
    { 
        OperationId[OperationId.length] = OpId.'Шаг 1';
    }

error TS1003: Identifier expected.  OperationId[OperationId.length] = OpId.*'Шаг 1'*;
```

Comment: `OperationId.push(OpId['Шаг 1'])` Как вы вообще программируете не зная базового синтаксиса языка?

Comment: Ну покажите что получилось

Comment: я нашёл два решение либо OperationId.push(OpId['Шаг 1']) и OperationId[OperationId.length] = OpId['Шаг 1'] оба эти вариатна выводят одну и ту же информацию

Comment: Ваш вариант сработал

Comment: я не так скопировал

Comment: Так что я удалил прошлый коментарий

Answer (score 0):

я нашёл два решение либо OperationId.push(OpId['Шаг 1']) и OperationId[OperationId.length] = OpId['Шаг 1'] оба эти вариатна выводят одну и ту же информацию